# C++ loading Data from a dat file using ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm working on a project for school where a part of what we have to do is to save data, in the form of team name followed by several integers into a `.dat` file and retrieve that data when the program is next run.

Note: counter is a variable that keeps count of the amount of teams that are present in the file, in this instance set to 3

```
    void load(int counter)
    {
        ifstream infile("saveFile.dat");
        string temp[25];
        int temp2[25][8];

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i ++)
        {

            getline(infile, temp[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                infile >> temp2[i][j];
            }

        }

        cout << counter;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            string name = temp[i];
            int gamesPlayed = temp2[i][0], wins = temp2[i][1], draws = temp2[i] 
   [2], losses = temp2[i][3],
                goalsFor = temp2[i][4], goalsAgainst = temp2[i][5], points = 
    temp2[i][6];
            CFootballTeam t(name, gamesPlayed, wins, draws, losses, goalsFor, 
    goalsAgainst, points);
            table[i] = t;
        }
    }
```

This is what my load function looks like but it appears to get stuck on the second line in the file and returns a white space followed by -858993460 for every team after the first suggesting that it's not reading any data even though data is present, here are the contents of my saveFile.dat file:

```
Manchester United
3 4 4 4 5 4 5
Manchester City
3 4 4 4 4 4 5
Chelsea
4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the program to continue reading the rest of the lines, not just line 1 and 2?

Thanks

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Post the input file content, not a link to an image of notepad.

Comment: What is the status of `infile` after each read? You should be checking for errors as you go.

Comment: 'infile' remains unchanged through out the runtime of this specific function @jwdonahue

Comment: The reason for the original post including an image was a formatting issue with the question where i could not force the output here to match the exact contents of the file, aka a new line at every /n position, but i will keep that in mind for the future, thanks @jwdonahue

Comment: @ilkam, no, it definitely changes state on every read. Check it's status after every read and respond to errors.  Also, verify that the file has been saved in ASCII or UTF-8 no-BOM.

Comment: Why do you have an array of `string` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: What happens if there are more than 25 lines in the text file?  What happens if `counter > 25`?

Comment: @jwdonahue The file is encoded in ANSI, the option to change it to UTF-8 no-BOM isn't available on file creation, sorry if i'm missing something. when trying to output values saved at every step i get 
Manchester United
3
4
4
4
5
4
5
whitespace
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
whitespace
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 25 is simply the upper limit of the possible teams that are to be stored in the table based on project requirements

also we're not allowed to use vectors even though they might make some jobs easier as we haven't officially covered them yet

Comment: ANSI should work.

Comment: getline has a return value. Check it for errors. getline in a loop until it fails. that would read all lines in a file. Always check everything for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not reading what you are expecting to. When you do `getline()`, the program reads in everything in the stream, until it hits a `\n`, then discards it. When you do `>>`, it reads until it hits white-space, but leaves that white-space in the stream. What this means is that when you go through the first iteration, you have everything good, but on the last `>>`, you are leaving the `\n` character. Then when you do the next `getline()`, it reads in the `\n`, giving an empty string and then you do `>>` on the text, and you are no longer putting everything in the right variables. Your input would look something like this:

```
Original Data
Manchester United\n
3 4 4 4 5 4 5\n
Manchester City\n
3 4 4 4 4 4 5\n
Chelsea\n
4 4 4 4 4 4 5\n

After getline()
3 4 4 4 5 4 5\n
Manchester City\n
3 4 4 4 4 4 5\n
Chelsea\n
4 4 4 4 4 4 5\n

After >>
\n
Manchester City\n
3 4 4 4 4 4 5\n
Chelsea\n
4 4 4 4 4 4 5\n
```

This means the compiler will likely set the values to some default, in your case, it looks like it is the minimum value. Ally you need to do is add `inFile.ignore()` at the end of each iteration to clear the `\n` from the end of the integers line.

Comment: i just tried adding cin.ignore(); to the end of each iteration in both the outermost loop and both of the loops all it seems to do is add a break that awaits for user input to proceed, doesn't seem to fix the issue itself

Comment: sorry, not `cin.ignore()`, it will be whatever your stream name is, so with the example you gave, it would be `inFile.ignore()`